# Why HTML 5 Canvas Does Not Draw Image Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to generate an image from a HTML 5 Canvas, but it's not "rendering" image content from the canvas.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/9kQPk/

It's supposed to be simple, I create a canvas, set a few things and a image using "drawImage" function, but when I try to generate an img html component, the image from canvas does not appear... Here is the JS:

```
$('#drawing').css("visibility", "visible");         
var drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");
var con = drawing.getContext("2d");         
drawing.setAttribute("width", 500);
drawing.setAttribute("height", 200);
con.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
con.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 200);                                           
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.deque.com/wbcntnt928/wp-content/dquploads/jquery_logo.png";
img.onload = function() {                
    con.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 250, 250);
};

//Generate Image
var drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");
var dataURL = drawing.toDataURL();
document.getElementById("result").src = dataURL;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting content of the canvas before you draw the image, put the generate image code in the onload function

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {                
    con.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 250, 250);
    //Generate Image
    var drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");
    var dataURL = drawing.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("result").src = dataURL;
};
img.src = "http://www.deque.com/wbcntnt928/wp-content/dquploads/jquery_logo.png";
```

note that the image must be of the same origin as the webpage drawing it to be able to save it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kQPk/2/show/)
[**Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kQPk/2/)

Comment: It's working now! Unfortunately, I can't say the same on my iPhone... It's not executing the toDataURL function... Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @CarinaPilar if you `console.log(dataURL)` right after setting it, does it contain any data? If it does, if you copy that string and paste it in as URL in a new tab, does it show an image? (and of course, is console showing any errors?)

Comment: It works on a PC browser, not on mobile... I don't know if the device can't get the image or what... Just nothing happens =/

Comment: Actually, it's working on Chrome and Samsung mobile browsers! It doesn't work on Safari... It is not perfect, but works for me, because my point is to show the web development issues... Thanks!